# AdMob Interstitial every fifth game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, admob

I implemented the AdMob Interstitial ad in my project and it works well. Now I want the AdMob Interstitial ad to only appear for every fifth game and not after every single game. Can someone help me?

Here is my code for the Admob in my GameViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    //addInterstitial
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 

    selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil]; }



    - (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
            if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
                [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]; }
```

UPDATE:

I have this code in the GameViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //addInterstitial
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] == nil){
        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: number forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue] >= 5){
        [self callAd];
        self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];

        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: number forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
        if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
            [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
        }
    }
}

- (void) callAd{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];
}


- (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial {
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:MyAdUnitID2];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    GADRequest *request2 = [GADRequest request];
    request2.testDevices = @[@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request2];
    return self.interstitial;
}

- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
}
```

And in the GameScene.m this code:

```
    - (void)showGameOver{

        //addInterstitial
        int score = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue]+1;
            NSNumber *newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newNumber forKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults:

```
- (void) callAd
{
  // Code to call your ad here
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
// If you haven't played yet, sets to 0

  if ([[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] == nil){
    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: num forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

  }

// If you have played

  if ([[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue] >= 5){
     [self callAd];  // ad is called


   NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: num forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // resets to zero
  }
}
```

And whenever a game is over:

```
int score = [[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue] 
+ 1;
NSNumber *newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newNumber forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // Sets to new value
```

The key can be anything really. At the top of your .m file put:

```
#define GAME_AMOUNT_KEY @"Game Amount Key"
```

**UPDATE**

Change:

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
            if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
                [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]; 
}
```

To:

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
            if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {


    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue] >= 5){
                    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]; 

                NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: number forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }

    }
```

And change (in ViewDidLoad):

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue] >= 5){
        [self callAd];
        self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];

        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: number forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

To

```
        [self callAd];
        self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
```

Comment: I have to declare GAME_AMOUNT_KEY in the Prefix.pch?

Comment: See the two additions (in the viewDidLoad) and at the end

Comment: Everything is fine except this error message: "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC" by this code line: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GAME_AMOUNT_KEY] intValue] + 1 forKey: GAME_AMOUNT_KEY];

Comment: Oh it's because it has to be a nsnumber. Wait a few minutes, ill update it.

Comment: With the "intValue" is something wrong but I don't know what :/ I think the number of games aren't added together.

Comment: Did you see my change?

Comment: Yes I saw your change ;) It isn't an error in xcode. It still doesn't work and I think this is because the number of games aren't added togheter.

Comment: In your simulator go to Reset Content and Settings

Comment: Oh no it was because after the ad was showing it wasn't resetting back to zero. See my latest update. Should work fine now.

Comment: Did you declare "back to zero" twice in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: After it calls the ad it assigns it back to zero and it does that when the view controller is first loaded.

Comment: I have the same problem :/ The AdMob Interstitial appears after every single game.

Comment: Post your edited code. You haven't copied my code example correctly.

Comment: Ok look at my update at the end. You we're checking to show the ad in the wrong place.

Comment: I added a second part to the update, make sure you see that too.

Comment: Thank you soo much WMios! You are the best;)

Comment: @StefanoVuottoCésar, glad I could help!